# insertAdjacementHTML is not a function at <anonymous>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to place a button after an already existing button on another website.  I'm trying to test it out in Chrome console, but can't figure it out.

```
var buttonPosition = document.getElementById('<button class="button black ">Black</button>');
```

This is the button that I want to place my button behind.

I then tried using the `.insertAdjacementHTML` function to get the button placed behind "button black"

```
buttonPosition.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<button>Hello</button");
```

Then I get the error message

> "Uncaught TypeError: buttonPosition.insertAdjacentHTML is not a
>   function
>       at :1:16"

This could be a rookie error, as I am very new to coding.  Any help at all will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: `element.appendChild(newElement)` ?

Comment: buttonPosition.appendChild(<button>Hi</button>); Something like that? @ProEvilz

Comment: yes but quote the html

Comment: You are trying to access the button by its outer HTML using the method for accessing elements by ID. Try `var buttonPosition = document.querySelector('button.button.black')` instead of `getElementById`. Your button doesn't have an ID, so `getElementById` returns nothing.

Comment: Just tried that and got this error: Uncaught TypeError: buttonPosition.appendChild is not a function
    at <anonymous>:2:16 @ProEvilz

Comment: Is the `<button>` element with classes `button` and `black` already in your markup or you are trying to create it?

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn thank you very much!  I got the button "Hello" to show up where I wanted it.  Next step is getting it to do the things I want it to.  I'm sure I'll be posting a ton of questions about that, but thank you.  This is the very first real world attempt at coding I'm making, so I really have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn I got it to work in Chrome console.  But I wrote the same code in tampermonkey and have the script on, yet it isn't adding the button now.  The //@include is just the website that the script will run on, right?  I can't figure out why it works in chrome console, but not in tampermonkey

Answer (score 1):

That's because the value of your `getElementById()` is not an element's ID name but an element. Try adding an ID on your button then pass its ID name to `getElementById()` as the value, like this:

HTML

```
<button class="button black" id="btn">Your button with an ID</button>
```

Javascript

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn'); // The button itself with an ID of 'btn'
var newButton = '<button>New button</button>'; // New button to be inserted

btn.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', newButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

**"document.getElementById"** itself clarify that it want "id" of the element. As per your snippet `var buttonPosition = document.getElementById('<button class="button black ">Black</button>');` I can say that you are missing the "id" but the element itself.

**Solution 1::**
Provide the id to the button and then try to use that id like:

```
<button class="button black " id="btn">Black</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var buttonPosition = document.getElementById('btn');
```

**Solution 2::**

If you are not able to provide the id, then use the class name.

```
var buttonPosition = document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0];
var newButton = '<button>Button</button>'; 
buttonPosition.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', newButton);
```